# Neo4j- convert Time String into Integer in query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, date-conversion

How can I convert String Time into Integer in Neo4j. I have been trying for quite a long time, but there does not seem to be any clear solution for it. Only solution, I found is to add a new property to my node while loading it from CSV. I don't want to do this.

I have Time in the following format:

```
"18:11:00"
```

and I want to do some subtraction on them.

I tried doing the following but to no avail:

```
match (st1:Stoptime)-[r:PRECEDES]->(st2:Stoptime)  
return st1.arrival_time, toInt(st1.arrival_time)
limit 10
```

But I get following output:

```
"18:11:00"  null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and do it using the function `apoc.date.parse`:

```
return apoc.date.parse('18:11:00','s','HH:mm:ss')
```

Running this example the output will be:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"apoc.date.parse("18:11:00",'s','HH:mm:ss')"│
╞════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│65460                                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The first parameter is the date/time to be parsed. The second parameter is the target time unit. In this case I have specified seconds (`s`). The third parameter indicates the date/time format of the first parameter.

*Note: remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [version compatibility matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).*

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This works like a charm. I am a noob in neo4j but I am getting deep into apoc now.